# Printing an array from a struct

Tags: c, arrays, struct, printf

When I try to print an array contained in an instance of a struct part of the result is what I'm expecting and other parts seem to be gibberish.  What is going on here?

Example output:

> $./makevector test
>
> NAME: test 16481592918288327671592918096327670000000000100011809530144490000159291832032767

My code is as follows:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

static int vec_length = 30;

typedef struct {
  char* name;
  int* vector;
} word_entry;

static word_entry entry_one = {NULL,NULL}; 

void MakeEntry(char* word, word_entry* entry){
 entry->name = word;
 int i;
 int this_vector[vec_length];
 srand(time(NULL));
 for(i=0;i<vec_length;i++){
   this_vector[i] = rand()%2;
 } 
entry->vector = this_vector;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
  int i;
  MakeEntry(argv[1], &entry_one);
  printf("NAME: %s\n", entry_one.name); 
  for (i=0;i<vec_length;i++){
    printf("%d",entry_one.vector[i]);
  }
  printf("\n");
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`this_vector` is a local array to `MakeEntry()`. When that function ends, that array goes out of scope. So `entry->vector` is pointing to something invalid and you get undefined behavior.

Answer (score 2):

Mulitple issues here - "this_vector" is local to MakeEntry, and goes out of scope when MakeEntry returns.

Also - I think you want some \n in your printfs

Finally - what output were you expecting?

Comment: Thank you, that was it.  I guess I have to declare a global array specifically for my struct instance and then modify it?  I was looking for a random binary string as the output to associate with the word.

Comment: Sure a global would work, or you can use the calloc() functions that others describe. And that should give you a string of 1's and 0's, but I'm not sure how that is useful? Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

Try something along these lines:

```
void MakeEntry(char* word, word_entry* entry)
{

      int i = 0;
      int *this_vector = calloc(vec_length+1, sizeof(int)); //Allocate an array of             Nelements x sizeof(int)

      entry->name = word;

      srand(time(NULL));

     for(i = 0; i < vec_length; i++)
       this_vector[i] = rand()%2;

      entry->vector = this_vector;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You create `this_vector` on the *stack*.  But then assign it to `entry->vector`, for use outside the function `MakeEntry`.

Once `MakeEntry` returns, `this_vector` is no longer valid, and is likely the source of your garbage.

```
void MakeEntry(char* word, word_entry* entry){
    int this_vector[vec_length];
    [...]
    entry->vector = this_vector;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion the problem is that you are printing numbers without any spacing, try with

```
printf("%d ",entry_one.vector[i]);
```

so that you can identify all the single ints in your array.

Oh well, read *chrisaycock* answer, I didn't notice you were assigning the whole `vector` from a stack allocated variabile. It goes out of scope after the local scope, you should dynamically allocate it:

```
entry->vector = calloc(vec_length,sizeof(int));
for(i=0;i<vec_length;i++){
  entry->vector[i] = rand()%2;
}
```

Comment: Here's what that did: NAME: test
16 48 60530528 32767 60530336 32767 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 809530144 49 1 0 0 0 60530560 32767

Answer (score 0):

```
entry->vector = this_vector;
```

`this_vector` is a local array type variable and is lost as soon as the function returns. But still the struct member hold reference to it.

Instead of allocating the array on stack, use `malloc` or any other dynamic memory allocater. Remember to `free` it when no longer needed.